# Azure portal failed to create a PowerBI workspace collection

Tags: azure, powerbi

When I try to deploy a PowerBI workspace collection the portal show an error message stating that the creation failed. What should I do?

Comment: What is the error message that you're getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has happened to me as well. I simply retried it and then it worked without any hiccups.

Let us know if you experience the same.